# Removing an item from a list having a particular class using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown, which when a particular option is selected removes an item from a list which has a certain class. However, my remove command:
 $('#coll-grouped-list li').hasClass('timeGroup').remove();
doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<select id="tGroup" name="tGroup" class="standard_select" style="width:200px;">
                  <option value="">Please Select</option>
                  <option value="hourGroup">Group by Hour</option>
                  <option value="dayGroup">Group by Day</option>
                  <option value="weekGroup">Group by Week</option>
                  <option value="monthGroup">Group by Month</option>
                  <option value="yearGroup">Group by Year</option>
                </select>

<ul id="coll-selected-list" class="droptrue sort-drop">
              </ul>
<ul id="coll-grouped-list" class="droptrue agg-drop">
              </ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('#tGroup').bind('change', function (e) { 
        if( $('#tGroup').val() == 'hourGroup') {
          $('#coll-grouped-list li').hasClass('timeGroup').remove();
          $("#coll-grouped-list").append('<li class="timeGroup">Hour</li>');
        }
        if( $('#tGroup').val() == 'dayGroup') {
          $('#coll-grouped-list li').hasClass('timeGroup').remove();
          $("#coll-grouped-list").append('<li class="timeGroup">Day</li>');
        }         
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasClass` returns boolean, so intuitively, it's not chainable, thus doing what you are doing in the example is invalid, as there's no method `remove()` in boolean class (`true.remove()`)

Try

```
$('#coll-grouped-list li.timeGroup').remove();
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an
>   element

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `.hasClass()` returns a boolean value, not a jQuery object, so you can't chain another jQuery function (`.remove()`) afterwards.

Try this instead:

```
$('#coll-grouped-list li.timeGroup').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#tGroup').bind('change', function (e) { 
     var $group = $('#coll-grouped-list');
     if( this.value == 'hourGroup') {
       $group.find('li.timeGroup').remove();
       $group.append('<li class="timeGroup">Hour</li>');
     }
     if( this.value == 'dayGroup') {
       $group.find('li.timeGroup').remove();
       $group.append('<li class="timeGroup">Day</li>');
     }         
  });
```